# Elegant way to fill array with numbers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is there more elegant way to make something similar in Swift?

```
var indexArray: [Int] = []
for i in -14...14 {
    indexArray.append(i)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try that

```
var arr: [Int] = Array(-14...14)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
let indexArray = Array(-14...14)
```